# TypeORM nested relation

Tags: node.js, nestjs, entity, typeorm

I have problem with TypeORM.

```
    this.productRepository.createQueryBuilder('product')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('product.attributes', 'attributes')
    .leftJoin('attributes.value', 'value')
    .addSelect(['value.item AS item'])
    .getMany();
```

it is my query. I want to add the nested value table item field to the attributes table (entity) field. I tried several ways but I didn't get any result

my expected output is:

```
 "id": 1,
        "companyId": 61,
        "createdAt": "11/16/2023, 5:33:18 PM",
        "updatedAt": "11/16/2023, 5:33:18 PM",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "productId": 1,
                "name": "name",
                "item" : "John"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "productId": 1,
                "name": "price",
                "item" : 15.30
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "productId": 1,
                "name": "stock",
                "item" : 231
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "productId": 1,
                "name": "color",
                "item" : "red"
            }
        ]
```

but I get this output:

```
 "id": 1,
        "companyId": 61,
        "createdAt": "11/16/2023, 5:33:18 PM",
        "updatedAt": "11/16/2023, 5:33:18 PM",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "productId": 1,
                "name": "name"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "productId": 1,
                "name": "price"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "productId": 1,
                "name": "stock"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "productId": 1,
                "name": "color"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: can you provide your entity relation